# Python and PyQT5, exe file is not running

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I wrote a program in Python 3.8 using the PyQt5 5.15.10 library.
Using pyinstaller (also tried auto-py-to-exe) I get the EXE file of the program.
When running on Windows 10 (where I developed the program), the program runs normally.
But when running on Windows 7, I get an error:

```
Failed to execute script 'pyi_rth_pyqt5' due to unhandled exception: [WinError127] The specified procedure was not found: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI23002\PyQt5\Qt5\bin
```

I tried to prescribe the import of libraries like this:

```
--paths C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI23002\PyQt5\Qt5\bin
```

It didn't help.
I also made a request without the --onefile parameter.
The folder with QT5 was at the specified path. But that didn't help either.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem like this:

1. Redone everything to Python 3.7 and earlier libraries (PyQt 5.10)
2. Installed the KB2999226 update on a PC with Win7
   After that, the program started

If it was possible to solve this problem without installing the old version of Python and libraries, please let me know.